# checkbox value when calling the method 'trigger' with click event

Tags: jquery

How can I can I get the correct current value in the click event to call via a trigger?

Html:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="mycheck" />
<br />
<span id="actual-value-inevent"></span>
<br />
<span id="actual-value"></span>
<br />
<button id="view-value">view value</button>
<br />
<button id="call-trigger">call trigger</button>
<br />
<button id="call-trigger-handler">call trigger handler</button>
```

Javascript:

```
$('#mycheck').bind('click', function(ev) {
    $('#actual-value-inevent').html('value in event : ' + $(this).is(':checked'));
});

$('#view-value').bind('click', function(ev) {
    $('#actual-value').html('value view : ' + $('#mycheck').is(':checked'));
});

$('#call-trigger').bind('click', function(ev) {
    $('#mycheck').trigger('click');
    $('#actual-value').html('value post trigger: ' + $('#mycheck').is(':checked'));
});

$('#call-trigger-handler').bind('click', function(ev) {

    $('#mycheck')[0].checked = !$( "input" )[ 0 ].checked;
    $('#mycheck').triggerHandler('click');

    $('#actual-value').html('value post triggerHandler: ' + $('#mycheck').is(':checked'));

});
```

If I call the "trigger ('click')", in the event the current value of the checkbox is pre-click.

On [this blog](http://www.bennadel.com/blog/1525-jQuery-s-Event-Triggering-Order-Of-Default-Behavior-And-triggerHandler-.htm) I find a solution, but I need to solve the problem in the function of the event, not to call the trigger.

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/kqrC9/1/) 
[example with solution](http://jsfiddle.net/kqrC9/2/)

possible solution by overriding the trigger method:

```
​(function($){

    var triggerOverwrite = $.fn.trigger;
    $.fn.trigger = function (eventType, extraParameters) {

        var stringEvent = '';
        if (typeof eventType == 'string')
            stringEvent = eventType;
        else 
            stringEvent = eventType.type;

        if (this.get(0).tagName.toLowerCase() == 'input' 
            && stringEvent == 'click' && $(this).attr('type') == 'checkbox')
        {
            $(this)[0].checked = !$(this)[0].checked;
            return $(this).triggerHandler(stringEvent, extraParameters);
        }

        return triggerOverwrite.apply(this, arguments);

    };


})(jQuery);​
```

[run](http://jsfiddle.net/kqrC9/3/)

Answer (score 0):

The click event applied to the check box is run before the click makes any changes.

So in your check box click event do the following:

```
$('#mycheck').bind('click', function(ev) {
    $('#actual-value-inevent').html('value in event : ' + !$(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

Comment: if I do this when calling a normal event, I have the wrong value

Comment: my bad, didn't check that. but why go to the trouble of overwriting the trigger method when your second example works fine? Why does it have to happen in the event function?

Comment: for me, this would be a more normal behavior of the method trigger. I might be wrong