# Why clicking on checkbox does not add the attribute checked='checked'

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors, jquery-events

When I click a checkbox, why does checked attribute is not getting added?. You can see the code here
http://jsfiddle.net/FCrSg/

Comment: Let's clear things out... are you expecting the 'checked' attribute to appear on the HTML?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602170/checkbox-value-when-calling-the-method-trigger-with-click-event

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What are you trying to do? Find out if its checked?

```
$('.user_roles').click(function(){ 
    console.log( $(this).is(':checked'));
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/petersendidit/FCrSg/1/

Comment: above solution work for me perfectly fine but i used also prop() function  that was also work perfectly fine but for same code dose not work whats the reason behind it please tell me

Comment: This response does not actually answer the question.

Answer (score 91):

The **HTML attribute** `checked` means: checked *by default*, when the page loads. This *won't* change when the checkbox is clicked.

```
<input type="checkbox" checked="checked"> <!-- The HTML attribute -->
```

The **DOM property** `checked` is actually the current state of the checkbox and is either true/false. This *will* change when the checkbox is clicked, but isn't visible when you inspect the HTML.

```
$('input:check')[0].checked == true;
// Whether or not the checkbox is currently checked
```

Comment: This is the answer. Forget about attributes.

Comment: Can you please cite your references?

Comment: are there any references? would much appreciate if you could share.

Comment: I'm sure everyone's moved on from this by now, but for the people asking for references: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox#attr-checked

Answer (score 2):

If you want to see it appear on the element displayed in the console, use the native [`setAttribute()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.setAttribute) method.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/FCrSg/2/

```
this.setAttribute('checked',this.checked);
```

So it would look like this:

```
$('.user_roles').click(function(){
    this.setAttribute('checked',this.checked);
    console.log( $(this) );
});
```

Then the console should give you:

```
<input class=​"user_roles" type=​"checkbox" checked=​"true">​
```

Though you normally wouldn't need the attribute set like that. Typically the property is enough.