# How do I get this jQuery event delegation to behave in IE7 as it does in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, jquery, cross-browser, internet-explorer-7, jquery-events

I have a bunch of checkboxes, and then this "master" checkbox that will uncheck, or check them all if it is checked.  Pretty common UI idea, you've probably seen it if you use GMail, or, you know, computers.

Each checkbox has an event that fires when you change it. Clicking the master checkbox will cause it to be fired on only the checkboxes that need to be changed.

In Chrome it works, in IE7 it doesn't.  That is, in Chrome clicking the master checkbox will aggregate clicks to the other boxes that need to be clicked, and their "onChange" events will fire.  In IE7 the clicks seem to aggregate, but the onChange events aren't firing.

Demo html

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <input id='master' type='checkbox'/>
  </li>
  <li>
        <input class='minion' type='checkbox'>
  </li>
  <li>
        <input class='minion' type='checkbox'>
  </li>
</ul>
<div id="log" style='background:#eee;cursor:pointer;'>
</div>
```

Demo javascript, jquery 1.7

```
$(function() {
    $("#log").click(function() {
        $(this).html('');
    });


    $(".minion").change(function() {
        var msg = $(this).is(":checked") ? "checked" : "unchecked";
        $("#log").append("<p> " + msg + " : " + new Date() + "</p>");
    });

    $("#master").change(function() {
        var toBeChanged = $(this).is(":checked")
            ? $(".minion").not(":checked")
            : $(".minion").filter(":checked");

        toBeChanged.click();
    });
});
```

And obligatory jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/hzcAF/

I'm pretty stumped.
        ​

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like you will need to fire the `change` event manually, then. This should work both in IE and Chrome:

```
$("#master").click(function() {
    $(".minion").prop("checked", this.checked).change();
});
```

([Demo at jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/hzcAF/3/))

Comment: This will duplicate the change event in browsers that are already throwing that event on the clicked "minions"

Comment: Setting the value will never trigger an event. My solution might fire change events for minions that were not really changed, yes, but never two events on one minion.

Comment: this is REALLY close, but I need to set the "checked" attr or prop so that the check boxes visually change. Something like `toBeChanged.attr('checked',this.checked).val(this.checked).change();`. I've updated the fiddle to isolate the problem area, and to make it so your solution won't fire events on redundant minions.  Could you update your solution to reflect the fiddle and explain if I should use attr() or prop()?

Comment: Awesome, thank you.  Why should I use `prop` instead of `attr`?

Comment: Oops, jQuery does not seem to work like that… [`val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/) does different things on checkboxes. You will need to set the `checked` [property](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4882020/1048572)

Answer (score 1):

Here's a good starting point:

http://jsfiddle.net/7qn63/5/

You'll probably want to be a bit more selective with the forced `change()` call.

Comment: You should never use browser detection like that. Do other browsers behave like IE7? Does IE10 still show the same bugs? Use *feature detection*.