# CSS on/off switch doesn't change underlying checkbox input

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have a [CSS on/off switch](https://proto.io/freebies/onoff/), using a `label` and the `for` attribute. The switches appear to work -- that is, the state changes and the switches animate -- but the underlying `checked` attribute on the hidden checkbox `input` isn't changing.

[Here's a JSFiddle that demonstrates the problem](https://jsfiddle.net/8pcees9x/) -- do an "inspect element" on the on/off switch to see the underlying input.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div class="onoff-container">
  <div class="onoffswitch">
    <input id="notify-by-slack" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="survey[notify_by_slack]">
    <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="notify-by-slack">
      <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
      <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <p class="name"> Slack </p>
</div>

<div class="onoff-container">
  <div class="onoffswitch">
    <input id="notify-by-email" class="onoffswitch-checkbox" type="checkbox" name="survey[notify_by_email]">
    <label class="onoffswitch-label" for="notify-by-email">
      <span class="onoffswitch-inner"></span>
      <span class="onoffswitch-switch"></span>
    </label>
  </div>
  <p class="name"> Email </p>
</div>
```

Here's my CSS:

```
.onoffswitch {
  position: relative;
  width: 90px;
  -webkit-user-select:none;
  -moz-user-select:none;
  -ms-user-select: none;
  display: inline-block;
}

.onoffswitch-checkbox {
  display: none;
}

.onoffswitch-label {
  display: block; overflow: hidden; cursor: pointer;
  border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); border-radius: 20px;
}

.onoffswitch-inner {
  display: block; width: 200%; margin-left: -100%;
  transition: margin 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}

.onoffswitch-inner:before, .onoffswitch-inner:after {
  display: block; float: left; width: 50%; height: 30px; padding: 0; line-height: 30px;
  font-size: 14px; color: white; font-family: Trebuchet, Arial, sans-serif; font-weight: bold;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.onoffswitch-inner:before {
  content: "ON";
  padding-left: 10px;
  background-color: #00C671; color: #FFFFFF;
}

.onoffswitch-inner:after {
  content: "OFF";
  padding-right: 10px;
  background-color: #EEEEEE; color: #999999;
  text-align: right;
}

.onoffswitch-switch {
  display: block; width: 18px; height: 18px; margin: 6px;
  background: #FFFFFF;
  position: absolute; top: 0; bottom: 0;
  right: 56px;
  border: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); border-radius: 20px;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in 0s;
}

.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-inner {
  margin-left: 0;
}

.onoffswitch-checkbox:checked + .onoffswitch-label .onoffswitch-switch {
  right: 0px;
}

.onoff-container p.name {
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  bottom: 11px;
}
```

Any help would be very much appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Comment: I changed the display style of the underlying checkboxes, and they seem to change. Is it possible the error comes when gathering/sending post values?

Comment: Looks fine to me too - easy way to check is to issue `$('#notify-by-slack').prop('checked');` in your console; it should return false when the Slack option is 'off' and true if it's 'on'. Works fine for me.

Comment: Ok, so it sounds like Firebug (I'm on Firefox) isn't picking up/showing the changes?

Comment: @omghai_8782 I'm not sure what you mean by "gathering/sending post values". Could you elaborate?

Comment: there is no bug when you check or uncheck the input the attr on the HTML never changes ...

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4882020/2887133

Comment: I was trying to predict what else could have been the problem. I don't see any code that sends data to the server, so my next place to look for problems (if this were me), would be to check the code that actually turns the checks into post-data before sending to the server.

Comment: @DaniP I see, thank you!